# Find another chart such that given set is a manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I have a question on some differential geometry homework:

---

Let $\alpha: I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : t \longmapsto \big( \sin (2t) , \sin(t) \big)$ be a curve, where $I := (-\pi, \pi)$.

**a.)** Show that $M := \alpha(I)$ is no submanifold by investigating $\alpha^{-1}$ on a suitable neighbourhood of the origin.

**b.)** Is it possible to find another coordinate chart in a neighbourhood of the origin, such that $M$ is a submanifold?

---

**ad a.)** The inverse of $\alpha$ is the map

$$\alpha^{-1} : M \longrightarrow I : (\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \longmapsto t = \tfrac{1}{2} \arcsin \alpha_1$$

but also

$$\tilde{\alpha}^{-1} : M \longrightarrow I : (\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \longmapsto t =  \arcsin \alpha_2$$

Because of the "almost self-intersection" of $M$ at the origin, the inverse maps $\alpha^{-1}$ and $\tilde{\alpha}^{-1}$ are not uniquely defined on an arbitrary open set containing the origin (see figure). Therefore $M$ is not a submanifold.

Is this argument valid?

[image]

**ad b.)** I would guess there is no other coordinate chart, because I don't see a way to find an open set containing the origin such that a coordinate chart is unique. However, I am not sure - and by the way the question is formulated I would assume that my intuition is wrong. Any ideas on this? If there is indeed no way to find another coordinate chart such that $M$ is a submanifold, how do I prove that very proposition?

---

**EDIT 1:**

In order to avoid confusion, here's how we defined a submanifold:

*$\underline{\text{Definition}}$:* A set $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold if for each $p \in M$ there exists an open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a map $\alpha : U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\alpha(U) = M \cap V$ and $U \subseteq{R}^{n-1}$ such that $\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Have you thought about tangent spaces?

Comment: We haven't gone deep into tangent spaces yet. Are you referring to **a.)** or to **b.)**? If you are referring to **a.)**, then one could argue, that the tangent space at point $p$ (here: the origin) is uniquely defined, and therefore the above set $M$ is no submanifold - since the tangent space at the origin is ambiguous (is this reasoning correct?) . However, if you are referring to **b.)**, then I am afraid I still draw a blank here.

Comment: OK, Octavius. Let me try something else. Suppose you have a chart on a neighborhood of the origin in $M$. What does that neighborhood map to in $\Bbb R^1$?

Comment: Hm if that neighbourhood is e.g. a ball, then it would map to some set

$$S = (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \cup (\pi-\varepsilon, \pi) \cup (-\pi, -\pi + \varepsilon)$$,

i.e. some subset of $(-\pi, \pi)$, where $\varepsilon$ is some small number. The map would not be continuous, I guess - contradicting the definition of a coordinate chart.

Comment: This chart has nothing to do with the original mapping.

Comment: I've updated my question, so that it includes how we defined a submanifold. I guess, my error in my last answer was, that I assumed you were talking about the "chart" $\alpha^{-1}$, which is in fact no chart. I would therefore correct my answer: a chart would continuously map onto a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. However, because of the "intersection" at $(0,0)$, there is no chart such that it continuously maps onto $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. bc. a sequence of points within a neighbourhood of the origin can approach the origin from 4 different "directions", but only from 2 directions in $\mathbb{R}$.) Right?

Comment: Yes, right. You can make an easy “connectedness” proof for this.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Shifrin, for your help on this!

Comment: Write up an answer so we can be done with the question. :)

Comment: I have now found the time to add the answer. I would appreciate it very much if you could see through it some time convenient and tell me your opinion on the correctness of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I hope this answer is correct. Please indicate any flawed reasoning.

---

Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ and let the set $V_{\varepsilon}$ be defined as

$$V_{\varepsilon} \enspace = \enspace \big\{ \; x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; \big| \; |x| < \varepsilon \; \big\} \quad . $$

The intersection $M \cap \partial V_{\varepsilon}$ is non-empty and there exists a $s_{\varepsilon} \in (0, \tfrac{\pi}{2})$, such that

$$\alpha(s_{\varepsilon}) \enspace \in \enspace M \, \cap \, \partial V_{\varepsilon} \quad .$$

Using this notation, one finds
\begin{align*}
 \big( M \, \cap \, V_{\varepsilon} \big) \, \backslash \, \{ (0,0) \} \enspace = \enspace \alpha \big( \underbrace{(-\pi, -\pi+s_{\varepsilon})}_{=: \, I_1} \big) \, \cup \, \alpha \big( \underbrace{(-s_{\varepsilon}, 0)}_{=: \, I_2} \big) \, \cup \, \alpha \big( \underbrace{(0, s_{\varepsilon})}_{=: \, I_3} \big) \, \cup \, \alpha \big( \underbrace{(\pi-s_{\varepsilon}, \pi)}_{=: \, I_4} \big) \; .
\end{align*}
(see figure).

[image]

The sets
\begin{align*}
 &\alpha \big( I_1 \cup I_4 \big) \cup \{0,0\} \quad , \\
 &\alpha \big( I_2 \cup I_3 \big) \cup \{0,0\}
\end{align*}
are connected. Consider now a chart $f$
\begin{align*}
 f : M \cap V_{\varepsilon} \longrightarrow J \subseteq \mathbb{R} \quad .
\end{align*}
Because $f$ is continuous, the following two sets are open and connected:
\begin{align*}
 &J_1 \enspace := \enspace f \Big( \alpha \big( I_1 \cup I_4 \big) \cup \{0,0\}  \Big) \quad , \qquad f\big( (0,0) \big) \in J_1 \quad ,\\
 &J_2 \enspace := \enspace f \Big( \alpha \big( I_2 \cup I_3  \big) \cup \{0,0\} \Big) \quad , \qquad f\big( (0,0) \big) \in J_2 \quad .
\end{align*}

However, $f$ is bijective, so since
\begin{align*}
  &\alpha \big( I_1 \cup I_4 \big) \cup \{0,0\} \enspace \cap \enspace \alpha\big( I_2 \cup I_3 \big) \cup \{0,0\}  \enspace = \enspace \{ (0,0) \} \quad .
\end{align*}
it must hold that
\begin{align*}
 J_1 \cap J_2 \enspace = \enspace \{ f\big( (0,0) \big) \} \quad .
\end{align*}
But both $J_1$ and $J_2$ are open, connected and $f\big( (0,0) \big) \in J_1, J_2$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
 J_1 \cap J_2 \enspace \neq \enspace \{ f\big( (0,0) \big) \} \quad .
\end{align*}
In other words, the intersection $J_1, J_2$ contains more than one element - contradicting the bijectivity of $f$. Therefore, $f$ cannot be bijective and thus cannot be a chart of $M \cap V_{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Looks good, except that $(0,0)$ is not in the domain of $\alpha$, so two slight modifications are needed.

Comment: Ah sure, I corrected that. Thank you again for your help!